# Java JTextField and (faulty) KeyListeners

Tags: java, swing, events

I've created a custom class that extends a JTextField and implements a KeyListener. Here is an extract of my class:

```
public class ChatBox extends JTextField implements KeyListener {
private boolean hidden;

public ChatBox(int x, int y, boolean hidden, MapFrame parent)
{
    setBounds(x,y,300,30);
    setBackground(new Color(255,255,255,40));
    parent.addKeyListener(this);

    if(hidden == true)
    {
        setVisible(false);
    }
    else
    {
        setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

I've then created the events for a KeyListener:

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("KEY EVENT DETECTED PRESSED");

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent key) {
    System.out.println("KEY EVENT DETECTED ON CHAT BOX");
    if(key.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
    {
            System.out.println("Showing message input...");
            setVisible(true);
            repaint();
    }

    if(key.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE)
    {
            System.out.println("Hiding message input...");
            setVisible(false);

            repaint();
    }

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Now, what I am aiming for is that the chat box appears when the user presses enter, and then disappears when they press escape.

When the user presses enter the chatbox/JTextField appears, and the "KEY EVENT DETECTED IN CHAT BOX" fires, but past this point, the keylisteners refuse to work. The "KEY EVENT DETECTED IN CHAT BOX" print doesn't even apppear.

The control has focus (I've even tried specifically giving it focus with requestFocusInWindow()), but the key listeners refuse to work, so I'm assuming it's something to do with the TextField 'overriding' them or something for the sake of input?

How can I get KeyListeners to listen for certain keys in a JTextField?

Regards,
Ben.

Comment: It may be worth noting that the parent is a custom JFrame, and I have added the key listener to the parent.

Comment: Use Swing Keybindings

Comment: @GuillaumePolet I added key bindings to the parent, but I have the same problem, once the TextField gains focus, the key bindings no longer work.

Comment: Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). This will get you a decent answer soon. Not providing one means that you ask others to do that for you and it is unlikely to happen.

Comment: just do emphasize @Guillaume's comment: don't use keylisteners **ever** - them working only if the component they are registered to is the focusowner typically is the least of the problems they pose. Keybindings are **the** way to go. If you want the parent of the focused component to handle those that are not handled by the component itself, use its inputmap of type WHEN_ANCESTOR

Comment: @kleopatra Thanks, I'll bear this in mind!

Comment: @GuillaumePolet Will do.